# Сумма смежнных элементов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вечер добрый! Какой метод использовать для нахождения максимального значения произведения смежных элементов массива [9, 5, 10, 2, 24, -1, -48]?

Comment: начните с цикла `for`

Comment: используйте reduce

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать reduce:

```js
let arr = [9, 5, 10, 2, 24, -1, -48];
let result = arr.reduce((prev, val) => {
  if (!(prev.prevVal * val < prev.max)) { 
    prev.max = prev.prevVal * val;
  }
  prev.prevVal = val;
  return prev;
}, {max: NaN, prevVal: NaN})
.max;
console.log(result);
```

Тут есть один тонкий момент, условие `if (!(prev.prevVal * val < prev.max))` нельзя заменить на казалось бы эквивалентное `if (prev.prevVal * val > prev.max)`, из-за того, что любое сравнение `NaN` с числом возвращает `false`.

Впрочем, банальный вариант с циклом `for` в данном случае может оказаться проще.

Answer (score 1):

Самым простым вариантом для Вас будет - воспользоваться обычным циклом for, примерно так:

```
var arr = [9, 5, 10, 2, 24, -1, -48],
   max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
   max = Math.max(max, arr[i - 1] * arr[i]);
}
```